# Error using the nlp-id package in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nlp, modulenotfounderror

I am working on an Indonesian NLP project and planning to use the [nlp-id package](https://pypi.org/project/nlp-id/) for removing stop words.

However, when I tried the code as explained on the website:

```
!pip install nlp-id
from nlp_id.tokenizer import Tokenizer 
tokenizer = Tokenizer() 
tokenizer.tokenize('Lionel Messi pergi ke pasar di daerah Jakarta Pusat.')
```

It gave me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [28], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from nlp_id.stopword import StopWord 
      2 text = "Lionel Messi pergi Ke pasar di area Jakarta Pusat"
      3 stopword = StopWord() 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nlp_id'
```

Can you help me troubleshoot the "ModuleNotFoundError" related to the missing 'nlp_id' module in my Indonesian NLP project?